# How to add a user-defined data type into a set?

Tags: java, abstract-data-type

this is my mock test from my professor and I having trouble writing it in Java.

This is the question:

> An ADT to manage a collection of students in a course is required. You
> can assume that there are no more than 100 students in any course. A
> student's record consists of ID (String), name (String), and GPA
> (double). There is no duplication in student IDs, but it is possible
> to have two or more students with the same name and/or GPA.
>
> Create a new type StudentCollection (it is equivalent to a class in
> Java). Except for the constructor, your StudentCollection type must
> support the following 3 public operations (feel free to add additional
> private operations as needed - but their scope have to be private)
>
> void addStudent(Student std): add a new student std to your
> collection. If there is a student having the same ID as std in your
> collection already, do nothing.
>
> Student searchByName(String name): search the student collection and
> return any student whose name contains name completely (case
> sensitive). Examples: "ABC" contains "ABC" completely; "ABC" contains
> "A" completely; "ABC" contains "C" completely, "ABC DEF" contains "C
> D" completely; "ABC" does NOT contain "CB" completely; "ABC" does NOT
> contain "abc" completely. If there is more than one matching student,
> your method can return any student. If there is no matching student,
> return null. int rankStudent(String sID): return the rank of a student
> whose ID is sID with regard to this collection. The ranking is done
> using students' GPAs. A student with the highest GPA has a rank of 1.
> In this example, let assume there are 4 GPA values [9.0, 8.5, 7.0,
> 8.5]. A student whose GPA = 9.0 has a rank of 1, a student whose GPA = 8.5 has a rank of 2 (there are 2 students who have the same rank of 2), and a student whose GPA = 7.0 has a rank of 4. If there is no
> student found with the provided sID, return -1.
>
> Create a StudentCollection object and use it in the main method
> (client code). Your client code must call all the above 3 public
> methods one or more times.
>
> You are NOT allowed to use the Java Collection Framework classes for
> this problem. Your code for this problem must be stored in a single
> file StudentCollection.java.

The ADT I'm choosing here is Set. Since the instruction doesn't allow me to use the Java Collection Framework, I have to manually implement all of the functions.

But here is the problem:
for the first function, the question ask me to write `void addStudent(Student std)` which when implementing a Set ADT, I cannot pass in a user defined data type `Student` into the function, I have done some research and we have to pass in a Set parameter instead of a user defined data type. Here is the code for class Student:

```
static class Student {
        private String ID;
        private String name;
        private double GPA;
        Student(String ID, String name, double GPA) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }
    }
```

let's say that we put in the `Student` class, then there have to be some `getters and setters` inside of the `Student` class. But the question limit the amount of public function to implement and all functions beside the three specify function above have to be `private`. How can a getter and setter be `private`? Is it possible?

The overall question is: How  to add a user-defined data type into a set?
I'm sorry if there is any explanation of mine is not clear. Please reply to this question if you have any further question.

Here is the code that I have been working on:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class StudentCollection {
    static Set<Student> manage = new HashSet<>();

    static class Student {
        private String ID;
        private String name;
        private double GPA;
        Student(String ID, String name, double GPA) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
            this.GPA = GPA;
        }
    }

    public static void addStudent(Student std) {
        manage.add(std);
    }

//    public static Student searchByName(String name) {
//
//    }
//
//    public static int rankStudent(String sID) {
//
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student std = new Student("s387", "nam", 3.7);

        addStudent(std);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For those that are wondering, ADT stands for abstract data type.

Comment: If your Student class is static, that means you can only have one student.  The only static field, method, or class in your code should be the main method.

Comment: You don't necessarily need getters and setters for accessing class' fields: you can just use `student.name` directly.

Comment: Of course, if you make the fields public: as the assignment says, only operations (as I understand it, methods) must be private.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That is not how static classes work in Java. Classes can only be static if they are nested within another class, and static means that they can exist without an instance of the enclosing class. You can have any number of instances of a static class.

Answer (score 1):

The `Student` class has to be public, with public getters.  Otherwise, you couldn't create a `Student` instance to add a student.

I went ahead and coded the `addStudent` method.  I'm leaving the rest of the code for you to finish.

You'll have to go over your class notes to verify, but this is how I would start coding the `StudentCollection` class.  There are no static fields or methods, other than the `main` method.

```
public class StudentCollection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentCollection sc = new StudentCollection();
        sc.addStudent(sc.new Student("10001", "George", 9.0));
    }
    
    private int studentLength;
    
    private Student[] students;
    
    public StudentCollection() {
        this.studentLength = 0;
        this.students = new Student[100];
    }
    
    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        for (int index = 0; index < studentLength; index++) {
            if (student.getSID().equals(students[index].getSID())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        
        students[studentLength++] = student;
    }
    
    public Student searchByName(String name) {
        
    }
    
    public int rankStudent(String sID) {
        
    }
    
    public class Student {
        
        private final double gpa;
        
        private final String sID, name;

        public Student(String sID, String name, double gpa) {
            this.sID = sID;
            this.name = name;
            this.gpa = gpa;
        }

        public double getGpa() {
            return gpa;
        }

        public String getSID() {
            return sID;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I understand your code but how can I apply an ADT, which I think Set would be the perfect fit for this problem, into this code?

Comment: "You are NOT allowed to use the Java Collection Framework classes for this problem."  That includes Set.